# how to add or register mail accounts in james mail server using java mail api

Tags: jakarta-mail, mail-server, james

How to add mail accounts to mail server through java code using mail api? Is it possible to add mail accounts using Runtime class?

Answer (score 0):

[The JavaMail API doesn't support this.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#newusers)  There's no standard network protocol for doing this.  You'll need to figure out how it's done for the mail server you're using.  You might be able to use the Runtime class to call a CLI command to add a user.